# cloudberry unexpected end of stream

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, amazon-s3, backup-restoration, restore, cloudberry

We lost an esx host recently and the VM's were being backed up with cloudberry server.  all restored fine except for one.  We keep receiving an errors "unexpected end of stream" when attempting to restore one VM. We are backing up to and restoring from amazon S3.

I have had zero luck getting in touch with cloudberry support.  I have been very disappointed as this is a production server.  Has anyone seen this error or have any ideas?  I have tried to recover from all 6 of the restore points that show were successful backups.

Comment: The answer provided seems to be from the vendor support so you can spell your ticket number if you have one, I'm sure that will speed this all up.

Answer (score 0):

This error should have been fixed in one of the recent releases of CloudBerry Backup. Do you use the latest version?